# javascript change remaining dropdown values depending on first

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, rows

My HTML table populates its rows dynamically. One of the table data is a dropdown with thesame options. What I want to do is when I change the value of the first, the remaining dropdowns on the other rows will have a selected value, thesame as what is recently selected.

If I change the selected value on the second row, the rest of the dropdowns will be like the second, without affecting the value of the first. Here are a few codes:

```
<table id="CheckDetails" width="60%">
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Amount</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row1">
<td><input name="date1" id="date1" class="" value="22-09-2013" /></td>
<td><select name="category" id="cat0" class="dropdown" >
    <option value="0">[-- Please Choose --]</option>
    <option value="1">References</option>
    <option value="2">Inspirational</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="entry" name="desc" id="desc0" value="1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="entry" name="amt" value="420.83333333333"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row1">
<td><input name="date1" id="date1" class="" value="22-09-2013" /></td>
<td><select name="category" id="cat0" class="dropdown" >
    <option value="0">[-- Please Choose --]</option>
    <option value="1">References</option>
    <option value="2">Inspirational</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="entry" name="desc" id="desc0" value="1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="entry" name="amt" value="420.83333333333"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row1">
<td><input name="date1" id="date1" class="" value="22-09-2013" /></td>
<td><select name="category" id="cat0" class="dropdown" >
    <option value="0">[-- Please Choose --]</option>
    <option value="1">References</option>
    <option value="2">Inspirational</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="entry" name="desc" id="desc0" value="1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="entry" name="amt" value="420.83333333333"/></td>
 </tr>
```

I am working with php for this project. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('select[name="category"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this), $nextAll = $this.closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('select[name="category"]');

    $nextAll.val($this.val())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/99fhv/)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, my problem now is that the description is supposed to change depending on the selected value. But it doesnt...